# Can PCI(e) claim fixed I/O registers

Tags: pci, pci-e

Can PCI(e)-device claim non-variable memory- or I/O-port-mapped addresses ? Or even fixed interrupts ?

Comment: No. It's all controlled by software.

Comment: Of course the assignments are controlled by software. But there are even 16550-compliant serial devices for PCI express. And the 16550-chips needs fixed I/O addresses (0x3F8, 0x2F8, 0x3E8, 0x2E8) and interrupts (IRQ 4, 3). So it looks for me that a PCI(e)-device can claim this fixed resources with its configuration-space so that it gets mapped properly on initialization by the firmware or the operating system.

Comment: I've never seen a PCI(e) serial port assigned to any of the I/O  addresses you listed. Usually it's something like 4050.\*  But if a PCIe device were assigned such an address, the assignment is done by software, not by the device somehow claiming the address.

Comment: \* I use PCIe serial ports literally every day, so this is **not** a case of saying I haven't seen it because I haven't looked.

Comment: That's a 16550-compatible PCI Express serial card: https://www.startech.com/de-de/karten-adapter/pex2s553 And at the bottom of the page there are a lot 16550 variants for PCI express.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I'm well aware of those. I use them literally every day. They  **do not** use the default COM port I/O ports.